# Как указать правила эффективного использования кеша для статических объектов?

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare

На моем WP сайте https://transscreen.ru/ хочу поставить для разгона по https://pagespeed.web.dev/ правила эффективного использования кеша для статических объектов так как гугл хочет этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В плагине W3 total cashe поставил чтоб не кешировалось часто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В cloudflare поставил 2месяца:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему гугл так и показывает что есть статичные объекты для который нужно время кеша увеличить? Где указать это в cloudflare ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не кэшируются шрифты, ну и js либо не кэшируется, либо выставлено маленькое время кэша. Вам показывает неэфективный кэш, так что может несколько причин.
Настройте кеширование через .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-javascript .js
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/xml .xml
AddType application/octet-stream .doc .mov .avi .pdf .xls 
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot 
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType application/x-font-woff2 .woff2
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    #кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
    </FilesMatch>
    #кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|txt)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
    #кэшировать флэш и изображения на месяц
    <FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>
    #кэшировать шрифты на месяц
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|woff|woff2|woff|otf|svg|eot)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>
    #отключить кэширование
    <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
        Header unset Cache-Control
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    #по умолчанию кэш в 5 секунд
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
    #кэшировать флэш и изображения на месяц
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    #кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    #кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 43200 seconds"
    #кэшировать xml файлы на десять минут
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
    #кэшировать шрифты на месяц
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff2 "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 2592000 seconds"

</ifModule>
 
 
### Удалить заголовок ETag (иначе есть проблемы с кешированием при включенном сжатии)
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None
```